# Combine 2 textbox text with delimiter

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, controls, string-concatenation

```
SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
sfd.Filter = "Text File|*.txt";
sfd.Title = "Save Text File";
if (sfd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
{
    string path = sfd.FileName;
    string left = string.Format(EmailTxtbx.Text, Environment.NewLine);
    string right = string.Format(PasslTxtbx.Text, Environment.NewLine);
    string[] leftSplit = left.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    string[] rightSplit = right.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);

    string output = "";
    if (leftSplit.Length == rightSplit.Length)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < leftSplit.Length; i++)
        {
            output += leftSplit[i] + ":" + rightSplit[i] + Environment.NewLine;
        }
    }

    using (StreamWriter bw = new StreamWriter(File.Create(path)))
    {
        textBox1.Text = output;
        bw.Write(output);
        bw.Close();
    }
}
```

Hey. I Have an issue. Lets Say I have 2 Textboxes I want The Textboxes 
Be Together:

**TextBox1:**

Test41
Test414
Test41

**TextBox2:**

Test55
Test56
Test54

**TextBox3:**

Test41:Test55
Test414:Test56
Test41:Test54

I want to load 2 files one to the first textbox and for the second textbox and combine With delimiter like ":" I Tried This Code And Its Not working. I'm new on c#.

Hope Someone Can Help Me

Comment: I'm confused, are you loading a file into one textbox or are you trying to join multiple textboxes with a delimiter?

Comment: Are the values in the textboxes separated by spaces or newline characters, or something else?

Comment: Hey @Greg I want to combine the textboxes with a delimiter

Comment: I am loading 2 files let’s say one for the emails and one for the password textbox1 = mails and textbox2 = passwords and I want to combine with delimiter like test@gmail.com:test

Comment: So you want to do `var example = $"{textbox1.Text} : {textbox2.Text}";`. Which would have example be the two values with the delimiter, that your intent?

Comment: Your code looks good to me.  What exactly is not working? What are you currently getting in the text box?

Comment: I get nothing I can build the project but it’s not working

Comment: @ZonEmOToRY "but it’s not working" has meaning only to you.  Be a bit more descriptive about what is not working, what you expect ect….The thought is: Kill them with information so they do not have to ask a question.

Comment: I’ll start from scratch. I have 2 textbox. In the first textbok it’s the mails. In the second textbox it’s passwords. What I need to do to combine the textboxes with “:” here example “test@gmail.com:test”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I’ll start from scratch. I have 2 textbox. In the first textbok it’s the mails. In the second textbox it’s passwords. What I need to do to combine the textboxes with “:”

Try this code snippet:

```
    var txt1 = textBox1.Lines.Where(a => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(a)).ToArray();
    var txt2 = textBox2.Lines.Where(b => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(b)).ToArray();
    var txt3 = "";

    for(int i = 0; i < txt1.Length; i++)
    {
        if (i < txt2.Length)
            txt3 += $"{txt1[i]}:{txt2[2]}{Environment.NewLine}";
        else
            txt3 += $"{txt1[i]}{Environment.NewLine}";
    }

    textBox3.Text = txt3;
```

Good luck.